# Proving limits for sequences

Tags: real-analysis

I need to be able to show that if we have the$\lim \limits_{n \to {+\infty} }$$y_n$ = ${+\infty}$ and the $\lim \limits_{n \to {+\infty} }$$z_n$ = M for some M $\in$ (0,${+\infty}$) show that the

$\lim \limits_{n \to {+\infty} }$$y_nz_n$ = ${+\infty}$.

Comment: For large $N$, $z_n > \varepsilon$ and you are basically done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want a proof “on first principles”.

Let $K>0$; you want to prove that there exists $k$ such that, for $n>k$, $y_nz_n>K$.

First choose $k_1$ such that, for $n>k_1$, $|z_n-M|<M/2$. In particular, $z_n>M/2>0$. This is possible because $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=M$.

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=\infty$, there exists $k_2$ such that, for $n>k_2$, $y_n>2K/M$.

Now let $k=\max\{k_1,k_2\}$. For $n>k$ we have
$$
y_nz_n>\frac{2K}{M}\frac{M}{2}=K
$$

Answer (score 0):

Given:
$\underset{n\rightarrow+\infty}{lim}y_{n}=+\infty\\\underset{n\rightarrow+\infty}{lim}z_{n}=M,M\epsilon\left(0,\infty\right)\\$

$M$ is on a closed interval therefor 
$y_{n}>z_{n}$

and that gives
$\\\underset{n\rightarrow+\infty}{lim}y_{n}\cdot z_{n}=\left(\underset{n\rightarrow+\infty}{lim}y_{n}\right)\left(\underset{n\rightarrow+\infty}{lim}z_{n}\right)\\=\left(\underset{n\rightarrow+\infty}{lim}y_{n}\right)\cdot M\\=+\infty $

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

- $\ds{\lim_{n \to \infty}y_{n} = \infty\iff \forall\ N\ \exists\ \tilde{n}\
  \mid \pars{~n > \tilde{n} \implies y_{n} > N}~}$.
- $\ds{\lim_{n \to \infty}z_{n} = M \iff \forall\ \epsilon > 0\,,\ \exists\
  \hat{n}\ \mid\ \pars{~n > \hat{n} \implies
  M - \epsilon < z_{n} < M + \epsilon~}}$

  ---

  \begin{align}
  \forall\ n > \max\braces{\tilde{n},\hat{n}}\,,\
  y_{n}z_{n} > N\pars{M - \epsilon}
  \end{align}